# How to highlight multiple dates from calender lib w/ python

Tags: python-3.x, calendar

I'm currently using the `calendar` library for Python to print out a calendar. I would like to highlight a list of dates on that calendar, however I'm having difficulty

**THE CODE:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
from time import strptime

COL_BLUE = '\033[96m'
COL_END = '\033[0m'

dates_dict = {2023: {'Jul':[16, 18, 31],'Aug':[1]}}
curr_year = datetime.now().year
curr_month = datetime.now().month
curr_day = datetime.now().day

#ANSI escape sequences for colors
colored_day = COL_BLUE + str(curr_day) + COL_END

calendar_output = (calendar.month(curr_year, curr_month))

#finds the first occurrence of today's date and changes its color 
highlighted_day = calendar_output.replace(str(curr_day), colored_day, 1)

print(highlighted_day)


for year, months_of_the_year in dates_dict.items():
  print(year)
  for month, dates_list in months_of_the_year.items():    
    month_no = strptime(month.title(),'%b').tm_mon
    print(month, month_no)
    calendar_output = (calendar.month(year, month_no))
    print(dates_list)
    for dates in dates_list:
      colored_day = COL_BLUE + str(dates) + COL_END

      calendar_output = (calendar.month(curr_year, curr_month))   

      highlighted_day = calendar_output.replace(str(dates), colored_day, 1)
    print(highlighted_day)
```

**CURRENT (left) and IDEAL (right) OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of rewriting the code, making some changes.
Please see if I correctly understood your request:

```
import calendar

from datetime import datetime
from time import strptime


def highlight_dates(year, month, dates_list):
    calendar_output = calendar.month(year, month)
    for day in dates_list:
        colored_day = COL_BLUE + str(day) + COL_END
        calendar_output = calendar_output.replace(str(day), colored_day, 1)
    
    return calendar_output


COL_BLUE = '\033[96m'
COL_END = '\033[0m'

dates_dict = {
    2023: {
        'Jul': [16, 18, 31], 
        'Aug': [1]
    }
}

curr_day = datetime.now().day

colored_day = COL_BLUE + str(curr_day) + COL_END

for year, months_of_the_year in dates_dict.items():
    for month, dates_list in months_of_the_year.items():
        month_no = strptime(month.title(), '%b').tm_mon
        highlighted_month = highlight_dates(year, month_no, dates_list)

        print(highlighted_month)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzOCh.png)